# Python: find a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, math

I need to solve task, there is a condition:
There is a a sequence of 17 consecutive natural numbers starting with `N`. For any number `a` of this sequence there is another number `b` from this sequence, such that `GCD (a, b)> 1`. Find the minimal N with this condition.

I use this code

```
for i in range(2, 100000000):
    not_division = 0
    lst = list(range(i, i+17))
    #print(lst)
    for j in lst:
        counter = 0
        for k in lst[1:]:
            if gcd_iterative(j, k) > 1 and gcd_iterative(j, k) != k:
                counter += 1

        if counter == 0:
            not_division += 1
            #print('%s have no delimiter' % j)
    if not_division == 0:
        print('%s SUCCESS' % str(lst))
```

But there is not sequence.
Maybe I do smth wrong.

Comment: Mathematical analysis rather than brute-force seems to be the way to go. Checking 17**2 conditions up to 100000000 times is fairly slow. For one thing -- note that the even numbers in the range don't need to be checked, nor do the multiples of 3, 5, or 7 (since every list of 17 consecutive numbers will contain at least 2 of each of those).

Comment: Remove multiples of 2, 3, 5 and 7. Then if the list has 2 multiples of 11 or 13 remove them too. If the remaining list is empty then you have the sequence.

Comment: The other issue is that `j` iterates over the whole list and `k` iterates over `1 .. end`. `k` should iterate over `j + 1 .. end`

Comment: How about 2,2,2, ...2 (the number 2 seventeen times)? So N=2

Comment: @JamesKPolk no, because it's 17 consecutive natural numbers

Comment: Ah, *consecutive*, got it!

Comment: So if your sequence contains a prime p>=17, then the sequence will fail because the smallest possible multiple cannot be in the sequence, right? That suggests you need to find a sequence with no primes in it to even have a chance.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yes, that's true

Comment: So maybe a modified sieve of Eratosthenes might be the way to go. You can store the prime power factorization of each number in the sieve for about the same work as an unmodified sieve, and doing so could greatly speed up gcd calculations.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks. I get prime numbers to 1000000000, but I didn't find this sequence.

Comment: There is something called a segmented sieve that can be used to sieve even larger ranges, but it's more complicated. It might be time to get some new ideas. Maybe a read of [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to tackle this with a less brute-force approach.

Some thought experiment first. Every other number will have the factor 2 in common. For the remaining 8 or 9, you need more factors. So for example you could have a factor of 3 common to some of them. Then another factor, and so on, e.g.:

```
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
* 3 * * 3 * * 3 * * 3 * * 3 * * 3
* * * 5 * * * * 5 * * * * 5 * * *
          ^       ^   ^       ^
```

So now do this in a more systematic way. Consider all prime factors smaller than 17. Try each combination of those, and for each combination each possible offset (but only those with at least 2 occurrences in the sequence). See which of these lead to a situation where every number has at least one partner. Then find the corresponding sequence using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Actually there are only 2 candidates:

```
 2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2
 3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *
 *  5  *  *  *  *  5  *  *  *  *  5  *  *  *  *  5
 7  *  *  *  *  *  *  7  *  *  *  *  *  *  7  *  *
 *  *  *  *  * 11  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 11
13  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 13  *  *  *
```

which is characterized by the first number *x* satisfying these constraints:

- *x* mod 2 = 0
- *x* mod 3 = 0
- *x* mod 5 = 4
- *x* mod 7 = 0
- *x* mod 11 = 6
- *x* mod 13 = 0
- ⇒ *x* mod 30030 = 2184

(computed using Sage function [crt](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/arith/misc.html?highlight=crt%20chinese#sage.arith.misc.CRT)) and the mirror image of the above

```
 2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2  *  2
 *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3  *  *  3
 5  *  *  *  *  5  *  *  *  *  5  *  *  *  *  5  *
 *  *  7  *  *  *  *  *  *  7  *  *  *  *  *  *  7
11  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 11  *  *  *  *  *
 *  *  * 13  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 13
```

characterized by

- *y* mod 2 = 0
- *y* mod 3 = 1
- *y* mod 5 = 0
- *y* mod 7 = 5
- *y* mod 11 = 0
- *y* mod 13 = 10
- ⇒ *y* mod 30030 = 7810

which is greater, so 2184 … 2200 is the first sequence satisfying your requirements:

- 2184 = 2<sup>3</sup> × 3 × 7 × 13
- 2185 = 5 × 19 × 23
- 2186 = 2 × 1093
- 2187 = 3<sup>7</sup>
- 2188 = 2<sup>2</sup> × 547
- 2189 = 11 × 199
- 2190 = 2 × 3 × 5 × 73
- 2191 = 7 × 313
- 2192 = 2<sup>4</sup> × 137
- 2193 = 3 × 17 × 43
- 2194 = 2 × 1097
- 2195 = 5 × 439
- 2196 = 2<sup>2</sup> × 3<sup>2</sup> × 61
- 2197 = 13<sup>3</sup>
- 2198 = 2 × 7 × 157
- 2199 = 3 × 733
- 2200 = 2<sup>3</sup> × 5<sup>2</sup> × 11

Which *should* be in range for your loop. Actually it should have been enough to loop up to 30030, the product of the primes up to 17. So if your loop really did finish, but miss this sequence, then there must be a mistake somewhere and knowing the sequence might help you debug that.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. There was a mistake in my solution